# Submitted ios app binary successfully and shown waiting for review, but after 5 to 10 mins display "invalid binary"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8, xcode6

Submitted ios app binary successfully and shown waiting for review, but after 5 to 10 mins when i refresh iConnect, its showing "invalid binary", please help me.
Note: now i m using 32bit architecture.
[image]
[image]

After refresh iConnect its shown invalid binary, like below
[image]

Comment: You have versions as 1.1 & 1.0.1... Check again...

Comment: Hi Parkar that is 1st time uploaded screen short, now its showing 1.0.1 @FahimParkar